# Mousemove event distence from the right hand side

Tags: jquery, mousemove

Using the mousemove event I want to get the pageX from the right side of the page.

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(event){
    if(event.pageX < 40){
        openSidebar();
    } else if(event.pageX > 310) {
        closeSidebar();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(window).width()` to get the window width and then calcualte when the sidebar should open / close.

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(event){
    if(event.pageX > $(window).width() - 40){
        openSidebar();
    } else {
        closeSidebar();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks.. its working..
$(document).on('mousemove', function(event){
                                if(event.pageX > $(window).width() - 40){
                                     openSidebar();
                                 } else   if(event.pageX < $(window).width() - 310){
                                     closeSidebar();
                                 }
                             });

Answer (score 2):

> i want mousemove event pageX from the right of page

Just minus the `event.pageX`  by the window width to get the pixels from right.

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
  var pegeXfromRight = $( window ).width() - event.pageX;
  document.write(pegeXfromRight);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```